# Comma before "that" clause at the end of a sentence

Tags: punctuation, commas, clauses

I recently wrote an article about writing comments in code. Upon reading it, a colleague of mine reacted to the following sentence:

> Any time you’ve spent more than 30 minutes getting something to work, and the fix ended up being some brief but unintuitive magical incantation that just has to be right there, that warrants a comment.

In particular, he mentioned that the rule he was taught in school for embedded clauses was that the sentence should read fine when the entire embedded clause (including the commas) is removed. That is:

> Any time you’ve spent more than 30 minutes getting something to work that warrants a comment.

This doesn't read well, and seems incorrect, at least to the two of us. However, with a comma re-inserted before "that", it reads fine:

> Any time you’ve spent more than 30 minutes getting something to work, that warrants a comment.

I realize I can re-write the sentence to avoid this oddity entirely, but my colleague and I were curious what the "true" rules are for a sentence like this. Is the original sentence outright incorrect, and if so, *why*? Is it technically correct, but idiosyncratic? Or is it just a little weird?

I've tried to dig into this myself, but haven't gotten to any clear answers. The closest clues I've found are a few sources that stress the distinction between restrictive and non-restrictive clauses, and that restrictive clauses should never have a comma. I *believe* the embedded clause here is a restrictive one (i.e., you couldn't leave it out), though as shown above, this one actually does require the comma to read reasonably. Those sources tend to focus on embedded clauses in the middle of a sentence though, not at the end, which maybe affects the rules? Alternatively, if the clause starting with "that" is a dependent clause (is it? it's not clear to me), and that warrants the comma despite it being a restrictive clause?

Hopefully you experts can help shed some light on the validity of this sentence!

Comment: Think about what happens if you remove the comma before "and".  Is it parenthetical or a breathing (and reading) aid?

Comment: In your version, I would understand _that_ as referring to the situation you have just described. In the shorter, comma-less version, I would understand _that warrants a comment_ as describing _something_ - making it an incomplete sentence.

Comment: @Henry: The comma before "and" I think could actually be either. That is, the sentence would be sensible without the embedded clause (i.e., parenthetical), but the comma is also there to be a breathing/reading aid in the sense that I think it reads okay even without that first comma there. I suppose your implication is that if it's not a parenthetical then the "remove the clause and commas, and the sentence should still read fine" rule wouldn't apply?

Comment: @KateBunting: It's the former I was going for — the "thing that warrants" is the situation described in the first part of the sentence. Which I suppose makes it a dependent clause? Which then implies a comma is warranted even in the shorter version?

Comment: @Henry: I *assume* what you mean is there could/should *already* be a comma before the "optional parenthetical" component, so if that parenthetical is removed, only the *terminating* "enclosing comma" should be removed. Leaving what sounds like a perfectly valid construction to me. (I don't care how the orthography indicates the semantically significantly pause after *getting something to work* - it ***sounds*** fine to me).

Comment: Yes, I consider that a comma is warranted. Use commas to make your meaning clear, not according to 'rules'.

Comment: @JonGjengset That's one heck of a long question to simply ask if the terminal _that_ clause should be set apart by punctuation. First, note that the _and_ clause  is not an embedded one but a coordinative one, so removing it is a matter of removing the second coordinate. The terminal _that_ clause is referential to the preceding coordination, but it's not a relative clause. Omitting the comma does make the terminal _that_ clause seem like a relative clause, which it isn't; rather it is a resultative adjunct.  In order to avoid potential ambiguity, the comma should be retained.

Comment: << Any time you’ve spent more than 30 minutes getting something to work, and the fix ended up being some brief but unintuitive magical incantation that just has to be right there ... that warrants a comment. >> rather laboriously twins a fragment with a main clause ('that warrants a comment.') and would be considered ungrammatical by some and unnecessarily heavy going by most others. Something more heavy-duty than a comma is preferable, if not a rewrite.

Comment: You definitely need the comma, but I‘m not convinced the sentence works anyway. I think you need a “dummy it” instead: *Any time you’ve spent more than 30 minutes getting something to work, it warrants a comment.*

Comment: @BillJ Thank you, that's helpful! The reason the question is longer than it technically needed to be is that I was also curious about the components of the sentence and how that impacts _why_ the comma was or wasn't needed. I also wanted to hear whether my colleague's rule of thumb from school was accurate, or otherwise why it would not apply here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's an interesting observation. I think for me it reads better without quite as severe a pause as ... would imply. Point well taken that the whole sentence should arguably be rewritten, but if I just did that and didn't ask, I wouldn't learn something new :)

Comment: @TinfoilHat I'm having a hard time putting my finger on why "it" in place of "that" sounds wrong somehow here. I think it's because there isn't a well-defined "it". "That" feels like it captures "the situation described thus far" even though there isn't a clear subject (which the "it" would bind to). Not sure how to ground that intuition though. Separately: I considered re-writing this in passive voice — _a comment is warranted_ — which also works, though it takes some of the air out of the sentence.

Comment: Look at it this way... *It warrants a comment anytime you do something stupid.* You can see that *that* just doesn’t work. (native AmE  speaker here)

Comment: I think either *it* or *that* works here. *That* is slightly more emphatic (or contrastive.) It's hard to do a comparative search and "it/that's a good idea" seems to give different results to "it/that's a magical experience". Also, "It warrants a comment anytime you do something stupid" is slightly different to "Anytime you do something stupid, it/that warrants a comment".